# Would my question about a database diagram be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I posted a question at [stats.se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56872/2750) over a week  ago (April 22 2013) about communicating database structure to a non-technical audience. It remains unanswered with multiple upvotes.

I suspect that it would be off topic here as a "brainstorming / idea gathering" question. But before missing out on the opportunity to tap this community for ideas, I would like to confirm my suspicion.

update: I have revised and reposted the question on this site: [How can I show a database graphically?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17738/12280)

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to GD.SE :)

Your question reminds me of [this other one we had here in the site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16690/how-can-i-convey-complexity-of-source-code-without-showing-code). I'd save the term brainstorming for something more in the lines of "How can I represent 'nnn' in an icon?". In this case, it would be a graphical representation of a database. "How can I show a database graphically", or similar.

If you present it in a way that is broad enough to be potentially helpful for other people, I think it would be a great question for GD.SE.

Comment: thank you for the feedback - I have posted the question here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17738/12280. Please let me know how I could improve it if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yisela. If it's worded in a manner which gains solutions to a specific issue rather than merely opinions, it could be very helpful to others.

"How can I show a database graphically" or similar seems on topic to me.

Comment: thank you for the feedback - I have posted the question here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17738/12280. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on the wording.